# Does the SimpleTest method drupalGetMails() prevent actual emails from being sent?

Tags: testing

During a SimpleTest, does the data intercepted by [drupalGetMails](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--simpletest--drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3a%3adrupalGetMails)() continue to your systems mail transport agent or is the actual send suppressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is only the getter.

```
// Use the test mail class instead of the default mail handler class.
variable_set('mail_system', array('default-system' => 'TestingMailSystem'));
```

in `DrupalWebTestCase::setUp` stops mails being sent. `TestingMailSystem` does nothing else but collect emails in the `drupal_test_email_collector` variable.

Comment: +1`ed for that nice tattoo you have, friend. Your answer did help me, but to be clear the upvote *is for your tattoo*.

Comment: It's not a tattoo, it's just face paint, sorry :)

Comment: And here I thought I had stumbled on some hard-core Drupal freak. (just kidding!!!) Have a good day, my friend.